# What is callback hell in C++ and why will it leak memory?

Tags: c++

I've been watching Herb Sutter's CppCon 2016 talk, in which he gave an example [around 37 minutes in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE&t=37m00s), something like this:

```
void f(shared_ptr<T> & ptr)
{
    obj.on_draw([=]() { ... }
}
```

He then says,

> I've heard it called callback hell, where you register a callback and
>   it has a strong owner--it happens to be a garbage-collected pointer
>   but it's a strong owner--but then you never get rid of it and it's
>   just stored there forever and now the object will never go away.

So he is saying that it's called callback hell and it will leak objects.
But I don't quite understand what's wrong with this code and why it will leak. Could someone explain this to me?

I've looked at others answers on stackoverflow, but they all seem to be about concurrency.

Comment: must be talking about memory ownership. Since there's no garbage collector in C, it's difficult to know when/who must free the allocated objects. `unique_ptr` can help, though.

Comment: If it is publicly available, link the talk.  Whether it is or not, say what slide # or what time in the presentation.

Comment: @RawN: It's not off-topic, it just doesn't capture enough of what Dr. Sutter was saying for anyone to answer without going and finding and watching the entire talk themselves.

Comment: Well, depending on what `on_draw` does it may keep the reference to the lambda forever. Thus the shared_ptr won't get garbage collected ever (because lambda captures by value, thus increases reference count). So I guess it is unsafe, because without knowing what `on_draw` does it may potentially lead to a memory leak.

Comment: ...garbage collected? This is C++. It's not getting garbage collected, regardless

Comment: @jaggedSpire In the sense that when the reference counter on `shared_ptr` goes down to 0 it is deleted. That's what `shared_ptr` is for after all.

Comment: fair enough, though that's not real garbage collection.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Whatever, its just a word :)

Comment: @freakish alas, I'm a rather pedantic individual. Sorry for splitting hairs.

Comment: @jaggedSpire well if you want to get truly technical, reference counting, such as is the implementation of shared_ptr, is indeed a legitimate form of GC. Just not the one you are thinking of.

Comment: Without even listening to the audio (no speakers on this computer), Herb seems to make his point pretty clear.  Look more closely at the reference graph to the right and contrast this code with the "good" version using expression capture of a `weak_ptr` instead.

Comment: Ok, we can help you learn this but we first need to know what your already grasp.  **Do you know why cycles cause problems with reference-counted object lifetimes?**

Comment: I'd use the term "callback hell" mostly to refer to the problem of understanding the control and data flow in code that relies heavily on non-blocking, continuation-passing interfaces, because your sequential logic gets broken up into lots of disconnected, disparate callables. Lifetime management may become difficult as a consequence, but that's just one of the problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Herb Sutter is talking about are **circular references**. He promotes a layered system, where resources aren't passed down to code that "reaches up"

Layer 1 - Owns the resources and Objects from Layer 2 (and below)

Layer 2 - Can`t have strong references to Layer 1 objects

What this ensures is, that the graph of dependencies don't get circles. So if Layer 1 frees all Layer 2 Objects then all resources get destroyed.
Why this is is important is quite easy: The resource counting from the C++ Std library can't deal with circular references (no ref-counting can), if obj a has a strong reference to obj b and obj b has a strong reference to obj a, then they will never be freed.

The ugly thruth is that this also is a problem if the circle goes over multiple references, possibly through software modules of different authors. Without a scheme like layers, you can`t just look at the code and say "There is no chance this will end up referencing the object I am calling from".
Herb Sutter proposes a convention, that unless you know the implementation you should never call a function that might keep a resource alive.

This is not saying that you should never do it, but if you follow a set of rules you can verify code per-layer or even per-file without knowing the rest of the system indepth. Otherwise you`d have to find all possible paths the function (on_draw) could take, to see if circular depencies could result - and if anything changes in any of the code possibly touched, then you have to do it again!

In that context "callback hell" is especially problematic since it kinda circumvents the type-system (not possibly to just allow interfaces from lower levels), and the callback could do anything.

If the callback doesnt save a reference to a resource, then use a plain pointer instead, this explicitely states to the caller that he doesnt need to worry about leaks. Not now or in the future.